# How to force an option after it has been overriden by vim plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have classic settings to `expandtab` in my `/etc/vimrc`:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

**How do I make sure they are not overridden by ANY plugin?**

**How to force them ignoring ALL plugins?**

Settings in `/etc/vimrc` are overwritten by language-specific settings. I want the opposite - any language-specific settings is overwritten by **my** settings in `/etc/vimrc`.

I appreciate the "smart" setting by filetype, but they have just got too smart - the default `vim` setup sets `noexpandtab` on some unrelated files. Even if I can find the culprit plugin, I don't want to fix them one by one - there is always a chance some new plugin will mess things up again. I would rather live with accidental spaces (where tabs are expected) then otherwise.

Comment: First, your custom settings have nothing to do in `/etc/vimrc`, put them in `~/.vimrc`. Second, if you don't want filetype plugins to override your mappings don't enable them.

Comment: @romainl, I want to set `expandtab` to overwrite plugin settings for **all users** on the host by default without letting any new user having these issues (even if I'm the only user and root). So, `/etc/vimrc` it the right option. I also want to overwrite only `expandtab` (without disabling any other plugins customization).

Comment: Whatever your users do will override what you put in `/etc/vimrc`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Users do not want to override anything - they want defaults. They simply do not have `~/.vimrc`. The point is to have **default** host-wide Vim configuration sane enough. In fact, just to add some context, these hosts are automatically provisioned and configured - there are no particular human users (only specialized accounts within the system which may be used generically by any developer).

Comment: Some options like `expandtab` need to be overridden when editing Makefiles. And if you impose tabs to be expanded, leave tabstop to 8. If you really have files mixing tab and spaces, when edited/published in tools like web interfaces for git, git-diff in console, ... you'll see code improperly indented.

Comment: @LucHermitte, the file type detection is just not perfect. My point is that it gives me much less frequency of problems if spaces are default rather than some automatic guessing based on numerous filetypes. If someone works often with Makefile, **they can go and change their `~/.vimrc`** or run `set noexpandtab` occasionally, or... there are numerous ways. Makefiles are just not a big deal.

Comment: @uvsmtid, Makefile setting are set in a ftplugin. This shall not be overridden by a global setting. Normally, it cannot be so. Unless you implement romainl solution. But if you never have Makefiles... it may be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to satisfy your requirements *while still enabling filetype plugins* I could think of involve overriding every possible filetype plugin.

The simplest is probably to do it in `/etc/vimrc` with an autocommand:

```
augroup expandtabFTW
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType * setlocal expandtab
augroup END
```

Comment: great! So far, I forced it by adding `set expandtab` in individual `~/.vimrc` (which was forgettable). The entire file was just this single line. The fact that `set expandtab` did work in `~/.vimrc` but didn't in `/etc/vimrc` was really frustrating.

Comment: @uvsmtid, if you want to force `/etc/vimrc` settings to be taken into account, require end user to `:source` this file from their `~/.vimrc`. I'm afraid there isn't much any other solution. May be if you drop a plugin into `/usr/share/vim/vim{version}/after/plugin/yourcompanysettings.vim`. Except this is not a good place to put anything as it should be reserved to contain only the official distribution of Vim. You may be interested in `:h 'rtp'` and `:h startup`.